# QtQuick: Change expand icon in TreeView

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qml, qtquick2

I want to exchange the standard expand icon in a TreeView, is that possible? I guess I would need to define states for the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide [`branchDelegate`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-treeviewstyle.html#branchDelegate-prop) in `TreeViewStyle` and use `styleData.isExpanded` to determine its state. For example,

```
TreeView {
    style: TreeViewStyle {
        branchDelegate: Rectangle {
            width: 15; height: 15
            color: styleData.isExpanded ? "red" : "green"
        }
    }
    //...
}
```